# Use pre-Big Sur icons in macOS apps and keep them persistent across updates

Tags: macos, finder, applications, icon

With Big Sur, macOS introduced a new icon design. Unfortunately, more and more apps are switching to that new icon design which I don't want as a user of Mojave, i.e. I would like to keep the old app icons.

I'm aware that it's possible to replace the icon resource in `.app` directories but that would only work until the update of the application. Is there a way to overwrite the icon for an application system-wide or maybe some existing software/daemon that can be used to automatically overwrite the Big Sur icon with the old icon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would have to create and run a script to overwrite the icons of each app system-wide. Here's an example - [Changing Mac OS X Application Icons Programmatically](https://www.sethvargo.com/replace-icons-osx/) - where the author has written a script to change the icon of an editor app. You can expand the script by adding more apps, along with the corresponding icons. If you need more help with this, do ask.

Comment: To change system apps (i.e. Finder, Terminal, Activity Monitor, etc), you'd need to modify their system files, but to do so, you'd need to disable SIP, unseal the new SSV structure, mount the system volume to perform modifications to them. Then you need to perform a snapshot of the system volume in order to reseal it. If you don't create a snapshot of the system, it will just boot to the last system snapshot (i.e. before you made the changes). As I am not sure how to perform these changes yet myself, I suggest you look into the new Signed System Volume (SSV) feature introduced in Big Sur.

Comment: @AVelj The user *did* say he was using Mojave.  Myself, I wish there was a resource (web site, whatever) that stored pre-Big Sur icons for a variety of third-party applications.

Comment: @MarcWilson Yeah, that would be nice. A big git repo containing a service and the icon list to auto-update the app icons would also work. But I doubt that it's legal to store those icons.

Comment: It's getting annoying doing it by hand, that's for sure.  Since I won't be installing Big Sur before .6, if at all, the icons just look weird.